# Printing bar codes on Star TSP100 in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, printing, activex, barcode

I have a [Star Micronics TSP100 printer](http://www.starmicronics.com/Printer/PrinterDesc.aspx?PageId=1&PrinterId=40) that I'm trying to use via [OPOS](http://www.starmicronics.com/absolutefm/absolutefm/attachments/142/2%20TSP100%20OPOS.pdf) from Delphi 7.  I cannot seem to make it print barcodes.

I can Open, claim and enable, print text and cut, but not print barcodes.

I have tried many methods of importing an Active X control to handle the printer, just like I have for a Bixolon Samsung POS printer, which works fine.

Any pointers welcome.
Code:

```
procedure TForm1.OpenbtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showmessage(inttostr( posprinter1.Open('StarTSP100')));
end;

procedure TForm1.ClaimbtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   showmessage(inttostr( posprinter1.ClaimDevice(0)));
end;

procedure TForm1.EnablebtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  POSPrinter1.DeviceEnabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.PrintbtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  POSPrinter1.PrintNormal(2,'A Test' + #10);
end;

procedure TForm1.PrintBCbtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  POSPrinter1.PrintBarCode(2, '1234567890', 108, 1000, trunc(POSPrinter1.RecLineWidth * 0.8), -2, -13);
end;

procedure TForm1.CutbtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  POSPrinter1.CutPaper(100);
end;

end.
```

Comment: What is the return value from `PrintBarCode`?

Comment: return value of 0 - the printer moves the paper back and forth but makes no mark

Comment: Sorry return value of 0 when height of 96 used - using a height of 1000 returns 106.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the printer supports barcode prinitng with the `CapRecBarCode` method.

You are setting your your barcode size to be 1000 high by (RecLineWidth * 0.8) wide. If the barcode is too big  for the paper or if the space you have assigned it is two small for the length of the barcode string it tends not to be printed.

Its possible that the height of 1000 is to large, so its not been printed, if this is the case the return value for `PrintBarcode` will be `106 - Illegal`. Try a much smaller number we use `60` or `96` for the height.

Comment: CapRecBarCode returns true.   I have changed the values for height to both 60 and again at 96  with no difference.  Also, it won't print any normal text until a cutpaper is sent.

Comment: Also I'm wondering which OCX I should be registering in Delphi

Comment: It prints when there is a line feed attached

Comment: @ReOsless just wanted to say thanks for the tips and sorted the problem

Answer (score 0):

I tested autor code and find problem.
You must set MapMode = 4; (in default MapMode = 1)
after you can print Code 39, EAN, codes print.

```
procedure TForm1.PrintBCbtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
POSPrinter1.MapMode := 4;  
POSPrinter1.PrintBarCode(2, '1234567890', 108, 1000, trunc(POSPrinter1.RecLineWidth * 0.8), -2, -13);
end;
```